# How to append empty row/column and how to use .empty() method properly?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm writing a function which takes item from a list (such as `item_x` in `[item_1, item_2, item_3, ..., item_n]`) and returns `dataframe_i` (can be empty).

I want to concatenate the returned dataframes into a single `final_result_df`, which also has the same length as the list (even all returned dataframes are empty). I need to check if the `final_result_df` is empty.

Here are my codes:

```py
def get_content_df(item):
    content = do_something()
    if content is not None:
        result_df = pd.DataFrame([content])
    else:
        result_df = pd.DataFrame([""])  # This line is my problem
    return result_df

my_list = [item_1, item_2, item_3, ..., item_n]

final_result_df = pd.DataFrame()
for item in my_list:
    result_df_i = get_conetent_df(item)
    final_result_df = pd.concat([final_result_df, result_df_i], ignore_index=True, axis=0)

print(final_result_df.empty)
```

The problem happens when all `result_df_i` fall into the condition that `content is None` is True.

1. If I use `result_df = pd.DataFrame([""])`, the `final_result_df` has the shape I want, but the `.empty` method returns the wrong value.
2. If I use `result_df = pd.DataFrame()`, the `final_result_df` does not have the shape I want, but the `.empty` method returns the correct value.

I believe the first condition must have some quick fix, but I'm not sure how to achieve that. I know this might not be how pandas was supposed to be used, but I haven't came up with a better idea. Any advice on other methods is also wellcomed.

Comment: Have you tried result_df = pd.DataFrame([]) ?

Answer (score 0):

**try:**

```
def get_content_df(item):
    if item is nan:
        item = "" 
    content = item
    if content is not None:
        result_df = pd.DataFrame([content])
    else:
        result_df = pd.DataFrame([""])
    return result_df
```

**I this is ok !, no?**

```
my_list = ["", ""]
my_list2 = [22, "dksjds"]


for j in my_list2:
    #print(i, get_content_df(i))
    res = get_content_df(j)
    #print(res)
    final_result_df3 = pd.concat([final_result_df3, res], ignore_index=True, axis=0)
```

even if the list is a series of nan, or ""s - it gets the result.

i.e. if list = [None] * 10, say it works...

hope this helps ...